# React doesn't render autocomplete off

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome

How do I make react render it?

```
<input
    id={field.name}
    className="form-control"
    type="text"
    placeholder={field.name}
    autocomplete="off"
    {...field}/>
```

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Capital "C" `autoComplete`. This is mentioned in the React documentation:

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes

Comment: Always throw an exception, not just silently ignore errors.

Comment: @Yaroslav It's possible React throws a warning for this, if not this will https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unknown-property.md

Comment: But also, it's not error because props can be anything.. how does React know when you're making your own prop or using an html attribute?

Comment: Props can't be anything for html tags.

Comment: I understand why you would think that's the case, but remember these JSX tags get transpiled down to function calls with a string that represents the tag type.

Comment: Nothing prevents inside that function call validate props if tag type is html tag. That's just extra work which nobody wants to do.

Comment: That's fair I guess. I would create an issue on react's github about it if I were you.

Comment: Few people are such zealots of code safety as I am.

Comment: None of these work for me... any other suggestions?
Also tried with Bootstrap FormControl and same...

Comment: @w3jimmy See my answer below

Comment: This does not work for me: https://snack.expo.io/@kopax/67b5bb

Answer (score 144):

You should put:

```
autoComplete="new-password"
```

This will remove the autocomplete

Comment: I really don't get why this works instead of "off". Weird.

Comment: @AjayGupta https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: @Pim Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: You are a legend, thanks! Also it makes sense, I wanted my new-password field to not be autocompleted :D

Comment: Probably chrome is recognising the `new` within the name. I named it now `autoComplete="new-off"` which makes a little bit more sense to me if it's not a password field and it works fine :D

Comment: This only worked for me once making sure the input was a direct child of a form element

Comment: It does not work if you have saved passwords for that domain.

Answer (score 26):

According to [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion), you have to set an invalid value to really turn the autocompletion off. In some browsers, autocomplete suggestions are still given even though the attribute is set to off.

This worked for me (react-bootstrap):

```
<FormControl
  value={this.state.value}
  autoComplete="nope"
  {...props}
/>
```

Comment: Wow, that's weird, but it's the only thing that's worked for me so far.

Comment: @Pim Mmm is it the same `autocomplete` and `autofill`? Because it does not work for me using Chrome. It keeps autofilling the form with previous values sent with the same form.

Comment: Only solution that works for me so far (chrome)

Answer (score 13):

If you've read the correct answer and still have this issue (especially in Chrome), welcome to the club... so check how I've accomplished it:

```
<form autoComplete="new-password" ... >
        <input name="myInput" type="text" autoComplete="off" id="myInput" placeholder="Search field" />
</form>
```

Notes

- form does not necessarily need to be the direct parent of the input element
- input needs a name attribute
- it also works with React-Bootstrap `<FormControl/>` tag (instead of `<input/>`)

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm trying with Chrome 67. Nothing. I still need a fake input with display: none! Very crazy!

Comment: thanks for feedback, but does your case tick all the 3 bullet notes?

Comment: In some cases I was still getting autosuggestions with this. See my answer for a more complete solution.

Answer (score 13):

Here's the "It works on my machine"

**Chrome Version 83.0.4103.116** and React. Looks like the trick that worked for me is to put it inside of a form and add the **autoComplete** attribute. Notice If you try this on a non-react app, you will have to do autocomplete with a lowercase C

```
 <form autoComplete="off">
      <input type="text" autoComplete="new-password" />
 </form>
```

and

```
<form autoComplete="new-password">
  <input type="text" autoComplete="new-password" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 9):

None of these solutions really worked on Chrome 80.

After hours of trial and error, this very strange hack worked for me:

1. Add `autoComplete="none"` to each `<input>` - Google skips autocomplete="off" now
2. Wrap your fields in a container : `<form>` or `<div>`
3. You need at least one valid input field with `autoComplete="on"`. This should be the last element in the container. So I added the following input field to the bottom of my form:

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  autoComplete="on" 
  value="" 
  style={{display: 'none', opacity: 0, position: 'absolute', left: '-100000px'}} 
  readOnly={true}
/>
```

Comment: This hack does not work for me (Chrome version 102.0.5005.61)

Answer (score 8):

Most of the suggestion here and elsewhere failed in Dec 2020. I think I tried them all: the form wrapper, setting autocomplete either to `off` or `newpassword` (neither worked), using onFocus, making sure I use `autoComplete` in React and not `autocomplete`, but none of them helped.

In the end mscott2005's approach worked (+1) for me but I also tweaked it for a more minimal example which I am posting as an answer for others:

No form was needed, just the two input tags:

- `autocomplete="off"` for the desired field:

  ```
  <input autoComplete="off" />
  ```
- `autocomplete="on"` for the fake hidden field:

  ```
  <input autoComplete="on" style={{ display: 'none' }}
      id="fake-hidden-input-to-stop-google-address-lookup">
  ```

The id is the best I have for documenting what is really a hack without using a comment.

Answer (score 7):

autoComplete="none" - works for me.

Comment: Welcome Alex.  Try to be more verbose with your answer.  Ponting out that your solution works because of the casing of "autoComplete" is important.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome autocomplete hell turns off by adding new-password attribute.

```
autoComplete="new-password"
```

In action looks like this:

```
<input            
type="password"
autoComplete="new-password"
/>
```

more discussion on:

[Chrome AutoComplete Discussion](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3500)

Answer (score 2):

Your browser will not respect `autocomplete='off'` if you have saved passwords for the page. Set `autocomplete='off'` in your project, refresh your project, then remove any saved passwords from your browser.

Answer (score 2):

In my case my EMail and Password fields were autoCompleted by Browser, it was overwriting initial values for both these fields on render.Well, nothing worked for me for more then 3 days, i was fed up with trying all the options. Then, i read how BROWSER intercepts email and password. I found that browser whenever sees password field in form then it initializes them email and password field of form itself no matter what (iff any password is saved in it's cache). Here is the solution to it: just add the following line in input/custom component field of password:

```
autoComplete="new-password"
```

And it will work.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @azium's answer, `<input>` should be put inside the `<form>` tag, then `autoComplete` works

Comment: Thanks ! I was looking for this

Answer (score 1):

First check if value is coming from auto complete feature

```
function isValueComingFromAutoComplete(_value, field) {
  return _value.length > 1 && inputs[field].value === "";
}
```

And then add the condition

```
function handleInputChange(_value, field) {
  if (!isValueComingFromAutoComplete(_value, field)) {
     // change state
  }
}
```

Note that it won't work if the input value has length 1.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not an password field please do:

**autocomplete="new-off"**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with just one line:

If you use the recommended way with "changeHandler()" and the components state, just insert:

```
changeHandler = (e) => {    
  if (!e.isTrusted) return;
  ... your code
}
```

More infos on that changeHandler()-Thing:
 https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: when google chrome autofills my input, e.isTrusted is true :D

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried many options, but what I ended up doing was to replace the `<form>` tag with `<div>` tag and manually manage each input that I had in that form.

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble with the auto complete on redux forms, a workaroud I did using redux forms; working 2021/03/08

```
if(userId!=undefined)
    {
      instance.get('/user/'+userId)
        .then(function(response){
          dispatch(initialize('user_create_update_form',{
            name:response.data.name,
            email:response.data.email,
            password:response.data.password,
            user_scope:response.data.user_scope.map((item,index)=>{
              return {
                value: item.name,
                label:item.name
              }
            })
          }));
      });
    }
    else
    {
      dispatch(initialize('user_create_update_form',{
        name:"",
        email:"Mail",
        password:"New Password",
        user_scope:[]
      }));
    }
```

Goal being: dispatching a form with dummy values.

Comment: Something else also succeeded, remove the password field, replace it with a send password reset button. Removing the field makes the browser not auto complete your form. When you create the user you send a password reset token from your database to the user email.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use useEffect**

```
function ScheduleComponent(props){
const [schedulecontent, setSchedulecontent] =seState({email:'',phone:'',date:'',time:''});

   function handlechange(event) {
      const { name, value } = event.target;
       setSchedulecontent((prevContent) => {
        return {
          ...prevContent,
          [name]: value
        };
      })
    }


    useEffect(() => {
//do something here...
    }, [schedulecontent.email,schedulecontent.phone,schedulecontent.date,schedulecontent.time]);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an older question, I couldn't find a simple approach and future compatible answer.

A very simple approach to solve the auto complete problem is to use the input field without making it unique in some way for the browser (if you can of course). For example if you don't add the `id` nor the `name` it is working out of the box.

The way to take the field name is to add the fieldName value within the onChange function:

```
<input
  type="search"
  className="form-control"
  placeholder="Quick Search"
  onChange={(event) =>
    columnSearch({
      columnName: column.name,
      searchValue: event.target.value,
    })
  }
/>
```

Also keep in mind that the input is not within a `form` HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are tired of trying different hacks...

Just add

> autocomplete="new-password"

In your password input field

Check this:-

```
            <form action="" className='w-1/2 border border-indigo-500 mb-10'>
                <label htmlFor="username">User Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" 
                autocomplete="new-password"/>
                <label htmlFor="phone">Phone</label>
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"/>
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
            </form>
```

Comment: I've downvoted your answer as it's the same as the [answer with the second most upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46452284/6126373) (or [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62853537/6126373) [ones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60210624/6126373)) but has an error that the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37503673/6126373) explains.

Comment: It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

[remove autofill details from your browser after doing autoComplete off in your input field then it works properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgv6y.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

this worked for me, try:

```
autoComplete="off" role="presentation"
```