# Dynamic loaded datalist options with AJAX in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, datalist

For different reasons I want to get rid of Jquery UI autocomplete function and replace it by HTML5 datalists with dynamic loaded options field. I searched on this topic quite a few days and found also different answers on stackoverflow, like [How do you refresh an HTML5 datalist using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610752/how-do-you-refresh-an-html5-datalist-using-javascript?rq=1) which I think is pretty close to what I search for.

I want the datalist for choosing tags, which will be written comma separated in the input field. The problem is that the datalist is only shown correctly for the first tag. The suggestion for the second one is not shown during typing "letters".

Now to the Process:

Typing: app

Server Response:

```
['apple','pinapple','snapper']
```

Shown datalist suggestion:

```
apple
pinapple
snapper
```

I now choose: apple, which is written to the input field, and afterwards:

Typing: ,in

Server Response:

```
['intest','instructor','insula']
```

Shown datalist suggestion: nothing, and this is the problem

BUT:

If I now hit backspace and delete the last sign, in the input field now stands:

```
apple, i
```

Then Firefox shows as options:

```
apple, intest
apple, instructor
apple, insula
```

I know that there is a comparison with the value or innerHTML Field, so that I use:

```
<option value="apple, intest">apple, intest</option>
```

Now the code example:

**HTML**

```
<input list="autocompleteList" type="text" class="form-control" name="Tags" id="Tags">
<datalist id="autocompleteList"></datalist>
```

**JS**

```
// Used for querying only the last word of input field
function extractLast( term ) { return split( term ).pop(); }

$( document ).on( "input","*[name=Tags]", function( e ) {

    var _this  = $(this);
    var input  = _this.val();
    var first_part;

    // If a first tag is already inserted, now extract it for later use
    if ( input.split(/,|,\s*| /).length > 1 ) {
        var temp   = input.split(/,|,\s*| /);
        first_part = temp.filter(function (el) { return el.trim() != ""; }).slice(0,-1).join(', ') + ', ';
        console.log("EXTRACTED FIRST PART " + first_part);
    } else {
        first_part = '';    
    }

    if ( extractLast(input).length >= 2 ) {
        $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
          type : 'POST',
          async:true,
          url: 'example.com/suggester',
            data: {term: extractLast( input )},
          success: function (data) {
                $("#autocompleteList").empty();
                for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                    $("#autocompleteList").append('<option value="' + first_part + data[i] + '">' +  first_part + data[i] + '</option>');
                }                               

                // Array of Tags
                console.log("DATA FROM SERVER: " + data);

                // For inspection
               console.log("CONTENT OF AUTOCOMPLETE LIST: " + $('#autocompleteList').html());
          }  
       });
    }
});
```

What I already have tested:

1. Changing: from input to keypress, keyup, keydown, change -> no success
2. Manually trigger events: _this.focus() or other --> no response
3. Using JQuery show() on the datalist
4. Embed the options into HTML-select. In this situation the datalist is also not working as expected, but the dropdown menu triggered by the select works fine and refreshes quickly.

So, finally:

How can I achieve, that the datalist options opens when typing letters without hitting backspace?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I stumbled upon this post which exactly describes the issue I was facing and was surprised to see no answers. 
The autocomplete attribute needs to be set. In your case

```
<input autoComplete="off" list="autocompleteList" type="text" class="form-control" name="Tags" id="Tags">
```

Note the capital C in the attribute.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503656/react-doesnt-render-autocomplete-off) post, the problem was in React which uses camel-cased attributes. I'm not using React, but it worked for me nevertheless.

Comment: This fixed my issue also, which is both great and annoying at the same time, because my client wants to have both the datalist functionality and the autocomplete turned on...

Answer (score 0):

I also had the issue of having to populate an HTML Datalist with Ajax via jQuery, and the elements would not show up without hitting backspace on Firefox, despite working on Edge and Chrome. The workaround posted by Shrestha Ghosh did not work for me, neither did another workaround posted [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1474137), which suggested setting the `autocomplete="off"` then immediately back to `autocomplete="on"` with JavaScript/jQuery (i.e. with [Element.SetAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) or [jQuery.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) respectively).

Instead, I noticed that the datalist would show up if I unfocused and refocused (i.e. clicked off then clicked in) the HTML `input` element. So, if anybody for which this issue is still relevant can use jQuery, it might be worth trying [jQuery.Blur()](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) and [jQuery.Focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) too; this is a solution I haven't seen posted yet (tested on Firefox 80.0 64-bit).

That is:

```
$("#your-input-element").keypress(function(){
    $(this).blur();
    $(this).focus();
}
```

Note [`keypress`](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) instead of [`keydown`](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/); this avoids triggering the blur and focus when trying to navigate down the list with the down-arrow key. It's not a fantastically elegant solution, but for my use case it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on Firefox where the  drop down is not showing even if the result came back (JS HttpRequest) and I can see it at the DOM.

the solution for me was to add empty  (as shown below) and replace it with the new data which came after sending the request.

```
<div class="form-group-input">
      <label for="client_name" class="hidden-label">Client Name</label>
      <input list="clients_list" autoComplete="off" type="text" name="client_name" id="client_name" placeholder="Client Name" >
      <datalist id="clients_list"><option value=""></datalist>
</div><!-- form group input -->
```

Thanks