# react controlled component updated by browser

Tags: reactjs

Here is a very simple login form. The problem I have is with Login Button. Obviously login button is disabled when there is no value in username and password control. But once I save my credentials in the browser, next time when I call the form it pops with the saved credentials. Regretfully the login button remains disabled.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, FormGroup, FormControl, FormLabel } from "react-bootstrap";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default class LogIn extends Component {
static propTypes = {
    onLoggedIn: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        username: "",
        password: ""
    };
}

validateForm() {
    return this.state.username.length > 0 && this.state.password.length > 0;
}

handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.id]: event.target.value
    });
};

handleSubmit = async(event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { onLoggedIn } = this.props;

    let data = {
        'username' : this.state.username,
        'password' : this.state.password
    };

    let url = `/slot_monitor/worker/login`;
    let response = await fetch(url,
        {
            method: "POST",
            body : JSON.stringify(data),
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
    let result = await response.json();
    if (result) {
        return onLoggedIn()
    }

    //todo login failed
    debugger;
};

render() {
    return (
        <div className="Login">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <FormGroup controlId="username" bssize="large">
                    <FormLabel>Username</FormLabel>
                    <FormControl
                        autoFocus
                        value={this.state.username}
                        type="text"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup controlId="password" bssize="large">
                    <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                    <FormControl
                        value={this.state.password}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        type="password"
                    />
                </FormGroup>
                <Button
                    block
                    bssize="large"
                    disabled={!this.validateForm()}
                    type="submit"
                >
                    Login
                </Button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: The potential problem source is - browser autofill isn't triggering onChange event, so FormControl doesn't know that it has data. An as far as I see FormControl don't support autocomplete attribute to disable this browser feature.
So, the way you can fix this - you should check the input element value (it will be easier with "_ref" attribute provided to FormControl) after your component did mount and update your state respectively.

Comment: Actually It does support autocomplete. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503656/react-doesnt-render-autocomplete-off but this didn't help either

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the problem is that your validate function is not bound to current context.

Try:

```
validateForm = () => this.state.username.length > 0 && this.state.password.length > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry but this didn't help. I tried to modify the form in functional way below and it didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Next time you call the form `this.state.username` and `this.state.username` are empty. Input fields could be filled out by the browser itself (autocomplete).

If you lift the state up you can solve your issue: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: State is lifted enough for this simple behavior, mate. Additionally autocomplete will trigger `onChange` anyway

Comment: Nowhere in the code I see ```this.state.username``` being fetched. ```this.props.onLoggedIn``` is probably saving something somewhere, but is it being re-fetched? If it needs to be fetched this should happen in the parent component (and passed down as a prop). Not sure about autocomplete triggering ```onChange``` reliably, I guess it pretty much depends on the browser implementation. Anyhow, it's a long shot, more details would help.

Answer (score 0):

I too think what [Mosè Raguzzini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1234087/mos%C3%A8-raguzzini) is saying is the problem. Not really able to test it out as for some reason I can't install `react-bootstrap` on my laptop. But, I do have something to say

If the problem is the `validateForm()` function not being able to see the values for `this.state.username` and `this.state.password` properly, it is all because `this` takes on different values based on rules that are not the easiest to remember

If you can use react hooks(available from React 16.8.0 onwards), do **consider using just a stateful functional component with useState() instead of a class-based component**. With a functional component you dont have to use `this`. And without `this`, every value is just found as expected

You can rewrite your component as a functional component like below

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, FormGroup, FormControl, FormLabel } from "react-bootstrap";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const LogIn = (props) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        username: "",
        password: ""
    });

    const validateForm = () => {
        return state.username.length > 0 && state.password.length > 0;
    };

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setState({
            [event.target.id]: event.target.value
        });
    };

    const handleSubmit = async(event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const { onLoggedIn } = props;

        let data = {
            'username' : state.username,
            'password' : state.password
        };

        let url = `/slot_monitor/worker/login`;
        let response = await fetch(url,
            {
                method: "POST",
                body : JSON.stringify(data),
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            });
        let result = await response.json();
        if (result) {
            return onLoggedIn()
        }

        //todo login failed
        debugger;
    };

    return (
        <div className="Login">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <FormGroup controlId="username" bssize="large">
                    <FormLabel>Username</FormLabel>
                    <FormControl
                        autoFocus
                        value={state.username}
                        type="text"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup controlId="password" bssize="large">
                    <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                    <FormControl
                        value={state.password}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        type="password"
                    />
                </FormGroup>
                <Button
                    block
                    bssize="large"
                    disabled={!validateForm()}
                    type="submit"
                >
                    Login
                </Button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

LogIn.Proptypes = {
    onLoggedIn: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default LogIn;
```