# Disable autocomplete on chrome (React)

Tags: html

I'm  trying to disable autocomplete on some inputs (or all of them inside some form), but I cannot do that! I looked for lot of examples, trying lot of answers there on stackoverflow, but still doesnt work.

This doesnt work:

```
<input type="text" name="asdf" autoComplete="off/nope/new-password/somethingtotallydifferent"/>
```

Also when I put `autocomplete="off"` inside `<form/>` element. Same result.

Can someone show me how to do that on latest versions of Chrome (and all modern browsers) without issues?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46452284/7906671)

Comment: Well but I dont have any password fields on that forms

Answer (score -1):

Did you try  this. With Capital 'C'

```
autoComplete="off"
```

Comment: yes of course, as I described in question, I tried that, but it seems like it is ignored by chrome